# How can you get median from aggregated excel data?

Tags: median, excel, aggregation

I have sets of aggregated evaluation data with the counts for each question (Q1/Q2/Q3) / response (scores of 1-5) option.

```
          1     2     3     4     5   <<< SCORE
Q1        0     1     5     7     15
Q2        0     0     3     4     21
Q3        15    0     3     4     4
```

I'm trying to find a way to *easily* calculate the median of the score for each of these questions. Finding the average is easy, but the median function wants a range of values. Is there a way to programmatically dis-aggregate this to a separate sheet to point the function at?

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30264155/median-for-frequency-distribution) (stack overflow) and [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/530046-find-medians-frequency-distribution-table.html).

Comment: The first link provided a working solution for me. Thanks!